# Handshake alert: unrecognized_name error

Tags: ssl, handshake, charles-proxy

I am using Charles 3.7 to debug SSL connections. I was able to view most of the HTTPS connections, however there is 1 or 2 sites that returned "SSLProtocol: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name" when I try to debug it, and I was unable to load the website with Charles on. I am able to do so using Fiddler. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this when using the latest beta Charles 3.10b9 on 10.10. We fixed by using a similar method to Shade's answer:

I opened info.plist in Xcode and did the following:

Under the JVMOptions (as oppose to VMOptions) key add the string:

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has more to do with a security improvement from Java 1.7 and server configuration than it does Charles.  Can you confirm which JRM Charles is using?  `help -> about java`

Here's an article about the same error message but after upgrading to Java 1.7:

http://www.pressingquestion.com/2030237/Ssl-Handshake-Alert-Unrecognized_name-Error-Since-Upgrade-To-Java-170

Do you need to use Charles for those sites throwing the error?  You can disable SSL Proxying per site if not.

Answer (score 0):

Add
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false to the info.plist in the Contents folder for the Charles application.
In:

```
<key>VMOptions</key>
<string>-Xmx512m -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using command line from project's path:

```
mvn clean install -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

Comment: This actually worked in my case (SSL certificate was present in keystore, yet I kept getting handshake failure with unrecognized_name). Could you perhaps elaborate why this works or point me to some information?