# W3C validator: "handshake alert: unrecognized_name"

Tags: html, w3c-validation, handshake

I am trying to validate my website on [W3C Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.healthdrop.in%2F) but I am getting below error, don't know why?

> IO Error: handshake alert: unrecognized_name
>
> [image: IO Error: handshake alert: unrecognized_name]

While my website is working fine on SSL.

I tried [Handshake alert: unrecognized_name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725118/handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error) , but no help.

**any guidance how to fix this much helpful. I didn't have that much knowledge of server.**

Comment: Please add a link to your website.

Comment: check the updated `W3C` link

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14884941/19068) — "certain misconfigured servers send an "Unrecognized Name" warning in the SSL handshake which is ignored by most clients... except for Java" — You would need to fix the misconfiguration of your server.

Comment: "AWS EC2" by itself doesn't mean anything. The *web server software* is the crux, not your hosting provider.

Comment: okay,But my ssl is working fine, and I am not facing any issue.

Comment: @urfusion "*... which is ignored by most clients*", which is why it appears to be "working fine".

Comment: and as per the above answer link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14884941/19068. this issue is for java : ` "Unrecognized Name" warning in the SSL handshake which is ignored by most clients... except for Java. `

Comment: To spell it out: Java, and mostly only Java, has a problem with connecting to servers which send an "unrecognised name" in the SSL handshake. The W3C service is likely written in Java. Your web server sends out an "unrecognised name" warning. Result: The W3C service cannot connect to your server. The solution: fix your server to not send this warning/fix its configuration. How to do this we cannot tell you since we know zilch about your web server.

Comment: I am working on solution second because there is no other option

Comment: any guidance how to fix this much helpful. I didn't have that much knowledge of server.

Comment: Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker here. The backend of the service is indeed written in Java, using the current Apache Commons HTTP client library. The exception this is coming from is thrown by that code, I don't know of any way to call that code differently that would cause it to be less strict like other clients and ignore the broken non-standard behavior of your server. So I have no way to workaround or prevent this on the W3C service side.

Comment: I'm also having same problem, but no useful answer

Comment: @KashifLatif : Check your server configuration and add `servername and serveralias` in your default-ssl

Comment: @urfusion: should I contact to hosting provider for it?

Comment: you can or you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068660/images-not-showing-on-twitter-error-fetching-the-page-failed-because-the-requ