# SSL Handshake Error - Shared Hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, shared-hosting, handshake

I just tried to run this page through the W3C validator and got the following error:

**IO Error: handshake alert: unrecognized_name**

Link: https://www.lightspeedmarketing.com/may-4th-musings-star-wars-day/

This is a blogpost from a wordpress site hosted with GoDaddy.

I called them to ask about a "SSL Handshake Error" but their guys didn't seem to know what I was talking about.  Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this with my webhost? Let me know if I can provide any more information about the website to clarify this issue.

Comment: seems to be a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580702/w3c-validator-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPS and SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)