# images not showing on twitter - ERROR: Fetching the page failed because the request timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, twitter-card

This is the url of my website https://www.healthdrop.in and I am getting

> ERROR: Fetching the page failed because the request timed out.

When try it on https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

I try each and every fix mention on different websites, but didn't get success.

Check this [for](https://www.healthdrop.in/health-articles/10-ways-to-improve-depression-and-anxiety-without-meds) all metas

I get in touch with [twittercommunity](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) and they say my `apache` config are not right and and the problem is

> The “other errors” is most commonly an SSL misconfiguration. In the
>   case of your server I’m seeing SSL3 alert read:warning:unrecognized
>   name which indicates you have an error similar to this one which was
>   also linked in the troubleshooting post.

So I run `apachectl configtest` to test my `apache` config and the result is

> Syntax OK

I check my website for SSL on [SSLLABS](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.healthdrop.in)

I tried with the step mention [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-whitelisted-unable-to-render-or-no-image-read-this-first/62736) but still no success.

Can anyone guide me more. I am using `AWS EC2 ubuntu` with `AWS S3` for images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** First of all try to debug your SSL, by the following command

```
openssl s_client -servername <hostname> -connect <hostname>:443 -state
```

if it print this message:

> SSL3 alert read: warning:unrecognized name

**2)** then try to add

```
ServerName www.healthdrop.in 
ServerAlias healthdrop.in
```

in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` or in virtual host file

**3)** then restart apache server by

`sudo service apache2 restart`